# Carousel and Sharepoint

Tags: branding

I need to add a carousel to SharePoint like the one in the following pic:

[image]

located on http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/07/jquery-carousel.html
How can I interface something like this to a Sharepoint list or library?
I was thinking of using Client Side Code to do this.. any ideas how this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compliment the other answers, your basic goals here are:

- Familiarise yourself with that carousel, how to build the markup it needs to generate the carousel. Do this independent of SharePoint, a static HTML file on your desktop, for example.
- Familiarise yourself with the client object model in SharePoint and how to get items out of the list you're interested in.
- Find out how to generate the markup you need on the page from the results of the client object model. You might find that jQuery can help with creating this (it could reduce the lines of code needed).

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of examples out there to do this. A simple Bing [search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=sharepoint%20jquery%20carousel%20slider&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=sharepoint%20jquery%20carousel%20slider&sc=0-22&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=a1ffbece39d847d2bb41a0ae6c424404) returns a lot of examples. Even searching [SP.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=image%20rotator) has significant options. I'd suggest doing a little research on what you are looking for and seeing what is possible with your current skillset. If you have questions with implementation at that point, we can be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a content editor webpart and add the carousel control on that list/doclib .
2. You can refer the link to get the jquery and required files : http://www.topsharepoint.com/avicia-free-sharepoint-online-theme#comment-27759

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/12/rotating-banner-sharepoint-jquery.html

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544663/Image-Carousel-Slider-in-SharePoint